# Rule engine in java & ruby (Suggest me a good approach)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jakarta-ee, rule-engine

I need to implement a rule engine either in java or in ruby (a independent project) which i have to integrate in a Java EE web-application so should I implement this in java because it will be easy to integrate or should I go with ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to integrate it into a Java EE web-application then I'd definitely suggest going with a Java-based option. You want to minimise the proliferation of different application stacks as much as you can, and integration across different stacks is always painful.

I think you will also find that the Java libraries in this area (rules engines / workflow) are more mature. I'd suggest looking at [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/): It is open source and well-proven.

Alternatively, if you really want to use Ruby but still want to integrate with Java / use Java libraries like Drools then [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) might be a good choice.

Comment: Hi mikera i came to know about 2 rule engine JESS(Work flow engine) nad drools by reading lots of document so can you please suggest me which one will be good

Comment: My requirement is something like i am checking code and if any standard method or approach is missing get a log or report or any kind of flag so which one will be good for me ?